# how to include a simple jquery file into a wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, php, jquery

ok this is my first time to include jQuery into wordpress and it has taken me the 2 full days trying to figure this out. No matter how many articles I read I cannot find a perfect example.

Ok so this is my plugin file... very simple.

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: jQuery Include Test
    Plugin URI: http://jquery.com
    description: A test to include jQuery.
    Author: blah blah
    Author URI: 
    */


// jQuery alert to pop up when the page loads.

    function pop_jquery_test() {
    $src = plugins_url('includes/jquerytest.js', __FILE__);
    wp_register_script( 'jquerytest', $src );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerytest' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action('init','pop_jquery_test');
```

and this is the jquerytest.js file that

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

$jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 alert('hi there');
});
```

now the question is how do i get this to work? in the sense when i activate the plugin, it pops-up like the jquery code above says.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because you're queuing jQuery after your own script. Try moving `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` to the top.

Comment: You can set the variable `$j` to be `jQuery.noConflict()`, but then you should use `$j` instead of how you are using it currently (`$jQuery`), and as Rutwick Gangurde said, enqueue jQuery _before_ your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jQuery is wrong. what you want is `jQuery(docu....` not `$jQuery(docu...`.

You should try to make sure the components work individually before you put them together (within reason of course), it will make troubleshooting MUCH easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pop_jquery_test() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    $src = plugins_url('includes/jquerytest.js', __FILE__);
    wp_register_script( 'jquerytest', $src );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerytest' );
}     
add_action('init','pop_jquery_test');
```

and in jquerytest.js file write code and test it

```
 jquery(document).ready(function(){
  alert('hi there');
});
```

Make sure that your file  path is correct otherwise jquery is not working.You can use firebug so you can check jquery is included or not in your file or path promblem.
Either use `$` or `jquery` or variable but not combine them `$jquery` in your code.

Comment: Please make sure that your post is properly formatted before posting